# Selenium, streaming audio from browser

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, audio

I'm using Selenium in Python for a project and I was wondering if there was a way to record or stream audio that is being played in the browser. Essentially I want to use selenium to get the audio and pass it to my application in Python so that I can process it.

Is there a way to do this in Selenium, or using another Python package?

Ideally I would want to be able to get any audio playing in the browser window irregardless of the source.

Comment: did you try to use an extension with hotkeys like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-audio-capture/kfokdmfpdnokpmpbjhjbcabgligoelgp?hl=en)?

Comment: @OleksandrMuliar I have seen this extension, but I want a programmatic way of accomplishing this task using python

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with just selenium, but it will be not so hard to implement it with python, just search python module or external program which suite your purpose

Comment: I have searched online extensively and have not found any modules that do this

Comment: from what I have seen in the documentation there is no method that gets audio from a browser

Comment: I see it possible to chose specific device for recording. Now way to do it for capture brwoser sounds ?  https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#device-selection